# don't call function if a nested element was clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component with a nested component, like this:

```
<div id="bla" onClick={() => this.handleOnClick(this.props.someParameter, this.state.someState, {id})}>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <ChildComponent />
    </div>
    ....
```

The nested component is technically an icon and it has it's own handleOnClick function.

If I click the child component icon both handleOnClick functions are called. But I want to call only the child component's function. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In the onclick event of nested component you can do e.stopPropagation()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [event#stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

On your child component's `handleOnClick` function, just call it like:

```
handleOnClick = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    ...rest of your code
}
```

I haven't worked with react, but this should work.

Answer (score 2):

Using `event.stopPropagation();` in your child component's `onClick` function will solve your problem.

[This method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) will prevent the event from propagating to your parent component

```
childOnClick = event => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    //.... your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your child component event handler, make sure you stop the event from propagating so it doesn't bubbles up to the parent div by calling [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```
class ChildComponent extends React {

  handleChange(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleChange}></button>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```